# Multiple Control Templates for a custom control in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, controltemplate, custom-controls

I am creating a custom control. The contents of the control will differ a lot when in different visual states.

Can I to achieve the above, apply different control templates to the same custom control? That is define more than one control template for a custom control? If not, any clues as to how I can do  this, without have as many custom/user controls as there are states?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define visual states inside a single ControlTemplate and also transitions between those states. Look for 'VisualStateManager'.